# Secure ways in sending confidential data to the server using HTTP Post

Tags: html, security, http, post

My objective: to send HTTP POST data securely to a server along with these two fields: `vendorKey` and `vendorSecret`

My temporary workaround is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vendorKey" value="70eb481bae5f7b37d13bae5030fb9870f54864c9">
<input type="hidden" name="vendorSecret" value="c5acda54553deef12c9660e85a3e2867126b41de">
```

But there are two big disadvantage about this:

1. It is seen on the HTML source code.
2. POST data can be seen using the Browser's Developer tools in HTTP Request Body

So I have two questions:

1. How can I submit those data using HTTP POST without showing it off on the source code?
2. HTTP POST data can be seen through the HTTP Request Body in Browser's Developer tools, how can I encrypt this or hide this?

Thank you so much in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using HTTPS. Without that there's, of course, no confidentiality.

> How can I submit those data using HTTP POST without showing it off on
>   the source code?

While you can greatly obscure secrets in the source using JavaScript, you can't actually hide them.

> HTTP POST data can be seen through the HTTP Request Body in 
>   Browser's Developer tools, how can I encrypt this or hide this?

You can't. No way, no how. Besides browser dev tools, debugging proxies can grab the data.

You'll need to come up with a design that doesn't pass sensitive data to the user.

Comment: What if I will use CURL?

Comment: Curl is just another HTTP/S client so the network traffic is visible to debugging proxies like netmon and Fiddler3.